# reducing the weighting of one of the x variables in glmnet

Tags: r

I can create a model using `glmnet`.
However if I know beforehand that the contribution of one variable is weak (say x[,1]) how can I reduce its contribution in the `glmnet` function?

```
library(glmnet)
x <- matrix(rnorm(100*20),100,20)
y <- rnorm(100)
fit1 <- glmnet(x,y)
print(fit1)
coef(fit1,s=0.01) # extract coefficients at a single value of lambda
predict(fit1,newx=x[1:10,],s=c(0.01,0.005)) # make predictions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but because penalized regression approaches assume that the variables are all scaled equally, *shrinking* the scale of a predictor variable should require a larger value of the parameter to characterize the same magnitude of effect, and hence a greater penalty, e.g.

```
x2 <- scale(x)
x2[,1] <- x2[,1]/100
fit2 <- glmnet(x2,y,standardize=FALSE)
coef(fit2,s=0.01)
```

shows that the first variable has been eliminated. (You have to force `glmnet` *not* to re-standardize the x-variables internally; you should make sure you've scaled the predictors yourself ...)

Comment: Thanks for the great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why just not remove it? I don't think you can the reduce the "contribution" of one variable. That variable makes noise to your prediction. When an independent variable added to a model the [R²](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) is increased, no matter what. If that variable does not have any relationship to dependent variable( which is your situation ) smaller amount of "contribution" is added to R².  If dependent(x) and independent(y) does have a relationship then the greater amount of R² is achieved which means you can explain the y with x better.

Comment: I can't remove it as I need to have a contribution from that variable, but dampened.